# Ocaml- how to define a type priority queue as a binary tree with |?

Tags: ocaml, priority-queue

I'm trying to define a priority queue as a binary tree, but keep getting a syntax error

```
    type 'a priority_queue = PriorityQueue of (Leaf | Node of 'a priority_queue * ('a*int) * 'a priority_queue)
```

I get an error when I do this as well

```
type 'a priority_queue = (PriorityQueue of Leaf) | (PriorityQueue of Node of 'a priority_queue * ('a*int) * 'a priority_queue)
```

How would I define this?

Answer (score 6):

I believe it should be

```
type 'a priority_queue =
| Leaf
| Node of 'a priority_queue * ('a * int) * 'a priority_queue
```

By using `priority_queue` when defining `Node`, we are saying that the left and right child may either be a `Leaf` or another `Node`. No need for any `|` floating inside the definition of a constructor.

### Edit

If you'd like to keep names of constructors for different types separate from each other, you can make use of modules. A quick Google search yielded [this page](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual004.html) which (ironically) opens up with priority queue examples. In particular, here's a simple module including your `priority_queue` type (based on the first section of that link):

```
module PriorityQueue =
  struct
    type 'a priority_queue =
    | Leaf
    | Node of 'a priority_queue * ('a * int) * 'a priority_queue
  end
```

The module `PriorityQueue` serves as a namespace for the declaration within it. So when you wish to use your priority queue, you can write things like this:

```
let leaf = PriorityQueue.Leaf
let pq = PriorityQueue.Node (PriorityQueue.Leaf, ("Hello from PriorityQueue", 1), PriorityQueue.Leaf)
```

Of course, that's really verbose, so for convenience you can open the module first:

```
open PriorityQueue

let leaf = Leaf
let pq = Node (Leaf, ("Hello from PriorityQueue", 1), Leaf)
```

Comment: Thanks! That kind of worked. It'd be something more like this

   `type 'a priority_queue =
   | PriorityQueue of Leaf
   | PriorityQueue of Node of 'a priority_queue * ('a * int) * 'a priority_queue`


But I'm still getting a syntax error, unfortunately.

Comment: I just realized that Ocaml reject the `PriorityQueue` so I replaced it with `priority_queue`. But I don't get why you want `PriorityQueue` to appear in the union cases.

Comment: AFAIK type names cannot start with a capital letter in Ocaml, hence PriorityQueue is rejected.

Comment: @akoprowski: Yeah, that one caught me by surprise - I actually code in F#, where uppercase type names *are* allowed.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde et al - Thanks for the tip!

I'd like to use the constructor PriorityQueue of leaf / node when defining, so that we don't accidentally confuse regular trees with priority_queues. Just wish I could find a way to do it. I suppose it's not a terribly big deal.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde - Thanks for the in depth explanation- a lot clearer now. I'm just still wondering if its possible to define type 'a priority_queue = PriorityQueue of Leaf and PriorityQueue of Node, because I don't want to confuse Leafs and Nodes, and PriorityQueue(Leafs and Nodes) within my module.

Comment: @Aspen: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Are you saying that you have already defined the constructors `Leaf` and `Node`, and that now you want to make a `priority_queue` type by using the `Leaf` and `Node` constructors?

Comment: @Aspen: Theres no problem using unique names for the constructors to distinguish priority queues from other trees:
`type 'a priority_queue = | PQLeaf | PQNode of 'a priority_queue * ('a * int) * 'a priority_queue`

Answer (score 4):

In case you are interested, [one of the examples](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.05/moduleexamples.html#sec18) of the OCaml manual is an implementation of priority queues whose datatype looks like yours -- a priority heap.

For an introduction to sum types, their syntax and some examples, see [Type declarations and pattern matching](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora016.html#toc17) in the excellent online book [Developping applications with Objective Caml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/).